# heroku db:push - Heroku client internal error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, push, taps

I am trying to put my local database to my existing app on Heroku and getting this error:

```
Sending schema
Schema:        100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:07
Sending indexes
schema_migrat: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
Sending data
3 tables, 3,621 records
schema_migrat: 100% |==========================================| Time: 00:00:00
 !    Heroku client internal error.===                         | ETA:  00:01:04
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

    Error:       undefined method `headers' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    Backtrace:   /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/utils.rb:173:in `reraise_server_exception'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/operation.rb:522:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in push_data_from_table'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/operation.rb:507:in `block (2 levels) in push_data_from_table'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/utils.rb:102:in `calculate_chunksize'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/operation.rb:491:in `block in push_data_from_table'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/operation.rb:481:in `loop'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/operation.rb:481:in `push_data_from_table'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/operation.rb:476:in `block in push_data'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/operation.rb:471:in `each'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/operation.rb:471:in `push_data'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/operation.rb:412:in `block in run'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/operation.rb:203:in `call'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/operation.rb:203:in `catch_errors'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/operation.rb:405:in `run'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/taps-0.3.24/lib/taps/cli.rb:172:in `clientxfer'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.30.3/lib/heroku/command/db.rb:192:in `taps_client'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.30.3/lib/heroku/command/db.rb:30:in `push'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.30.3/lib/heroku/command.rb:193:in `run'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.30.3/lib/heroku/cli.rb:25:in `start'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.30.3/bin/heroku:16:in `<top (required)>'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
                 /Users/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'

    Command:     heroku db:push
    Plugins:     heroku-sql-console
    Version:     heroku-gem/2.30.3 (x86_64-darwin10.8.0) ruby/1.9.2
```

The weird thing is, that yesterday was everything ok and I was able to push my local database to Heroku without any problems.
Today, I just add another column to my database and wanted to push it live - and got this error.

I attempted to push the database live 3 times, all attempts failed.

Where could be a problem?

Comment: I remember having a problem like this due to a mismatch in ruby-versions locally and at Heroku: do you happen to use 1.9.3 locally? It might help if you switched to 1.9.2 for the `db:push` (assuming you use rvm, otherwise suggesting that you use rvm to do this).

Comment: I ended up repushing and it worked perfectly, might have been a hiccup with Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helped me just to specify needed tables:

```
heroku db:push --tables table1,table2
```